# How to do a custom sort on a list

Tags: .net, sorting

I have a list which is made up of the following elements

```
<1, 2-3, 4-5, >6
```

when I sort it I get

```
<1,>6,2-3,4-5
```

but would like to get it in the proper order.

I coded this whichs works properly however I find it to be grossly verbose and would love to bring it down to 2,3 lines of code

```
_data.Sort(delegate(SourceEntity a1, SourceEntity a2)
{
  if (a1.Dimension1.StartsWith("<") && a2.Dimension1.StartsWith("<")) return 0;
  else if (a1.Dimension1.StartsWith(">") && a2.Dimension1.StartsWith(">")) return 0;
  else if (a1.Dimension1.StartsWith("<") && a2.Dimension1.StartsWith(">")) return -1;
  else if (a1.Dimension1.StartsWith(">") && a2.Dimension1.StartsWith("<")) return 1;
  else if (a1.Dimension1.StartsWith("<")) return -1;
  else if (a1.Dimension1.StartsWith(">")) return 1;
  else if (a2.Dimension1.StartsWith("<")) return 1;
  else if (a2.Dimension1.StartsWith(">")) return -1;
  else return a1.Dimension1.CompareTo(a2.Dimension1);
});
```

SourceEntity contains a property called Dimension1 which contains that value that I am trying to sort on.

Comment: Are you sure that e.g. ">1" should be equal to ">9"?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression to filter out non-numeric characters, and then compare:

```
_data.Sort(delegate(SourceEntity a1, SourceEntity a2)
{
    Regex nonNumericCharacters = new Regex(@"\D");
    return nonNumericCharacters.Replace(a1.Dimension1, string.Empty).CompareTo(nonNumericCharacters.Replace(a2.Dimension1, String.Empty));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems, the only case when the lexical sort doesn't do what you need is comparing "<" with a number. So, the following should be enough:

```
return ((a1.Dimension1.StartsWith("<") && !a2.Dimension1.StartsWith("<"))
    ? -1 : a1.Dimension1.CompareTo(a2.Dimension1));
```

Comment: VladV, this really doesn't solve anything. Have you actually tried this code with the example list?

Answer (score 0):

```
 var trimChars = new[] { '<', '>' };

 _data.Sort((a1, a2) => 
      a1.Dimension1.TrimStart(trimChars)
        .CompareTo(a2.Dimension1.TrimStart(trimChars)));
```